# Windows 8 store app unit tests fail in VS 2012

Tags: unit-testing, windows-8

I am developing a Windows 8 store app. I added unit tests by choosing **Solution** >> **Add** >> **new project** >> **Unit Test Library (Windows Store apps)**. I am then able to run the tests fine.

However, I then add a reference to my original Windows 8 store app project ([following the instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj159318.aspx)), and when I try to run the tests again, I get the following error:

```
------ Discover test started ------
WriteTestCaseStarted
WriteTestCase Took Time = 3.0004
========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:00.1350024) ==========
------ Run test started ------
Updating the layout...

Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...

Registering the application to run from layout...

Deployment complete. Full package name: "c078c431-2a0d-4494-8dd9-47ae01ac938d_1.0.0.0_neutral__chny7cy2kxrnj"

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.8770198) ==========
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Commenting out the following line from **App.xaml** solved the problem:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
```

Why?

Comment: I was doing the same and all worked OK, does your app runs OK ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple things can cause this. Here are a couple I've found:

- Application tag in app.xaml setting any properties (like RequestedTheme)
- App.xaml referencing a ResourceDictionary which uses custom attached properties.

Try commenting out contents of App.xaml to see if that helps.

Comment: How did you find these problems ?

Comment: Pain, suffering and time :)

Comment: Gotcha.  I followed your advice, basically moving everything out of App.xaml to finally get mine to work.  I spent days trying to debug the useless error messages, but I guess this works too.  Hooray!